# Using from/size in Elasticsearch - "using [from] is not allowed in a scroll context"

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a quite standard query that seems to be using the scroll API - how do I change it to use the from/size (non-scroll) API?

My query:

```
            {
                "query": {
                  "bool": {
                      "should": [
                          { "match": { "object.id": query } },
                          { "match": { "object.name": query } },
                          { "match": { "object.content": query } },
                          { "match": { "object.type": query } }
                      ]
                  }
                },
                "_source": "object.*",
                "from" : from_result,
                "size": RESULTS_PER_PAGE
            }
```

The error returned is:

```
b'{"error": {"root_cause": [{"type": "action_request_validation_exception", "reason": "Validation Failed: 1: using [from] is not allowed in a scroll context;"}], "type": "action_request_validation_exception", "reason": "Validation Failed: 1: using [from] is not allowed in a scroll context;"}, "status": 400}'
```

Comment: Which URL are you hitting?

Comment: localhost:9200/index_name/_search

Comment: do you have any query string parameters that you're appending? like `scroll=1m` or something similar?

Comment: Ah yes, I had some middleware adding {'scroll': '15s'}. Thanks

Comment: Cool, glad you figured out